# Importance of Intersect Except order

Tags: sql-server

I am using Sql Server and my question is the following:

Do this two codes give the same result:

1. A except B intersect C except D intersect E
2. A intersect E intersect C except B except D

?

Comment: Write some code and find out. Post your results here so everyone knows.

Comment: "this two codes". There is no code here. Show some actual SQL and your schema details, and preferably some sample data and desired output, and it might be possible to answer. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some guidance on how to create an example that's actually usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand the definitions of each operation, then I think you would understand what gets returned from both examples.

> EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t
>   output by the right input query. INTERSECT returns distinct rows that
>   are output by both the left and right input queries operator.

So in order of operations:

```
1. A except B intersect C except D intersect E
```

- The `A Except B` will return rows from `A` that aren't output by `B`;
- `A` only rows will `Intersect` with `C`
- `AC` rows will `Except` with `D`
- `AC` only rows will `Intersect` with `E`

Resulting in `ACE` rows

```
2. A intersect E intersect C except B except D
```

- `A Intersect E` returns both `AE` rows
- `AE Intersect C` returns `AEC` rows
- `AEC Except B` returns `AEC` without `B`
- `AEC` Only rows `Except` with `D` returns `AEC` without `D`

So concluding `1. ACE rows` and `2. AEC rows`, it would appear that the both would return the same results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Both result in AEC, but this does not guarantee that they return EXACTLY the same rows of AEC. Do you get me?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but they should return the same rows, if the data is the same each time. Think of this as the `Distributive` property in Math.

Comment: Actually it's the `Associative` property I was thinking about.

Comment: Don't forget that Intersect have a higher precedence than except. does this change the thing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question: It mainly relate to the precedence of intersect over except. so A except B intersect C is not like A intersect B except C.